# For each loop in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt

How to write a `for-each` loop in xslt 1.0 which only consider `Subbranch` elements with ID=11 and 12, ignoring 13 and 14.

```
<root>
  <branch ID='1'>
    <subbranch ID='11'>
      <Values DataType='String'>
        <Value StringLength='3'>abc</Value>
      </Values>
    </subbranch>
    <subbranch ID='12'>
      <Values DataType='String'>
        <Value StringLength='3'>def</Value>
      </Values>
    </subbranch>
    <subbranch ID='13'>
      <Values DataType='String'>
        <Value StringLength='3'>uvw</Value>
      </Values>
    </subbranch>
    <subbranch ID='14'>
      <Values DataType='String'>
        <Value StringLength='3'>xyz</Value>
      </Values>
    </subbranch>
  </branch>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xsl:for-each](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256166.aspx) with an XPath expression that only matches the first two subbranches:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="branch/subbranch[@ID='11' or @ID='12']">
        <!-- Emit something... -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, alternately:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="branch/subbranch[position() &lt; 3]">
        <!-- Emit something... -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Hamidi for your answer,but i need generic option, where we we can limit childnodes(<subbranch>) by its position.

Comment: @user, the second template in my answer should be appropriate, then.

Comment: i have some stuffs which i'm doing inside <xsl:template match="branch"> and i'v to limit the child nodes from the above template only,but the above specified solution wont work inside template(match="branch")... so plz can u suggest me a solution where i can get position of childnodes(subbranch) inside <xsl:template match="branch">

Comment: @user, if your template matches `<branch>` elements, then you only have to modify the XPath expression into `subbranch[position() &lt; 3]` instead of `branch/subbranch[position() &lt; 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to avoid `for-each` constructions except when dealing with `<xsl:key>`.
You should use a `match-template` and `apply-templates` construct and just not consider the unwanted values.

This XSLT applied to your source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subbranch[@ID='13']"/>
<xsl:template match="subbranch[@ID='14']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<branch ID="1">
    <subbranch ID="11">
        <Values DataType="String">
            <Value StringLength="3">abc</Value>
        </Values>
    </subbranch>
    <subbranch ID="12">
        <Values DataType="String">
            <Value StringLength="3">def</Value>
        </Values>
    </subbranch>
</branch>
</root>
```

By matching the unwanted values in empty templates you avoid those parts of the XML to get processed, e.g. `<xsl:template match="subbranch[@ID='13']"/>`